# How to set IntroJS step on a fixed element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, intro.js

I got a fixed element (because that element has to stay fixed at a certain position) with these attributes:

```
style="position: fixed; width: 270px; right: 60px; height: 500px;"
```

Whenever I press through the introJS steps, it would show the highlighted area a little bit off:
[image]

How I call IntroJS:

```
  var intro = introJs(); 
  var options_before = {

    steps: [
      {
        element: ".bar",
        intro: "this is step 1"
      },
      {
        element: "div#fooId",
        intro: "Why does step 2 look so weird?="
      }
    ]
  }

  intro.setOptions(options_before);
  intro.start();
```

I tried to reposition (changing `top` and `margin` attributes) and resize that element, but the highlighted area of introJS would never fit to the area I want to hightlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an id to element and in introJs steps

steps: [
      {
        element: "#yourID",
        intro: "Your Description"
      }
]

Try this before you call intro.start().

```
intro.onafterchange(function(targetElement) {
    if(this._currentStep == 1){
        overlay = document.getElementsByClassName("introjs-fixedTooltip");
        for(i=0; i<overlay.length; i++) {
            overlay[i].style.left = '10px';
            overlay[i].style.right = '10px';
            overlay[i].style.position = 'fixed';
            //Set css properties like this.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it turned out the way I displayed in my question.

Comment: may be "div#fooId" element selection is going wrong. See if edited code works for you.

Comment: It works, but you also have to add a "position: fixed", i.e. 'overlay[i].style.position = 'fixed';' (Otherwise the overlay loses it's focus if you press the next- and previous-button.)

If you would add this to your answer, then I'd accept your's a the solution.